# Why is Two-Face mad at Jim Gordon?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight

In *The Dark Knight*, Harvey Dent says Jim Gordon can only say sorry after he lies to a loved one by saying they will be fine only to know they will die. But what is Gordon being asked to apologize for? Not saving Rachel in time?

Comment: Er, and *his crooked cops being in on the plan*?

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question there

Comment: It is odd that Gordon didn't do anything about his crooked cops before it was too late. He rather fought against Harvey by saying that Maroni would have infiltrated his office too and kind of just forgot about his own department.

Answer (score 4):

When first Batman apprehend Lau from Hong Kong, Harvey Dent argued with Gordon that he will keep him under his custody but Gordon denies.

Joker forced some cops under Gordon to kidnap Rachel and Harvey Dent. Gordon failed to supervise those men under him.

And much more things which forced Harvey Dent to turn him into a bad guy. When harvey dent investigate those corrupted officers and he came to know that those cops are worked under Gordon. Which indirectly makes him responsible for all crime. Hence Gordon has been asked to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

**Mostly because Jim was working with the Batman when they saved him over Rachel**

In the movie, we can see Two-Face going after a number of persons involved somehow in Rachel's death including cops.

As viewers, we know that it was the Batman who gave Jim the "order" to go after Rachel and leave Dent to him but Harvey doesn't know that. Therefore, he deems Jim responsible for Rachel's death.

It is also worth noting that Harvey Dent was nicknamed 'Two-Face' long before he was hurt and that is because he always had a dark side and resentment towards the corrupt police department. His resentment for the police department might have played a part in that personal attack on Jim.
(This is not stated in the film but is from 'Batman the Dark knight returns' comic in which 'Two-Faced' is "cured" both physically and mentally but remains 'Two-Face' because it is who Dent truly is).

TL;DR : Jim is being asked to apologize for the unfairness of his decisions as the commissioner that "caused" (from Two-Face's PoV) his loved one's death.

Comment: Actually Batman went after Rachel and Gordan was meant to go after Harvey but the Joker switched them around because he knew Batman would go after Rachel; "the way you threw yourself after her"

Answer (score 0):

He is angry because he warned Gordon earlier about working with corrupt cops, but Gordon shrugged off his concerns. And those corrupt cops in Gordon's unit kidnapped him and Rachel so Two-Face blames Gordon's negligence which ultimately resulted in Rachel's death and his disfigurement.